# UITableView calling the another UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have two UIViewControllers with tableview. When the first cell loads in the second UIViewController it calls the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the same class but when it loads the second cell it calls the first viewControllers `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

My code as follows:

**SecondViewController:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NotificationsTableViewCell *cell = [self.notificationsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NotificationCell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[NotificationsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"NotificationCell"];
}

NSMutableDictionary *cellData = [self.databaseCall transactionFromDatabase:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", cellData);

cell.goalNameLabel.text = [cellData objectForKey:@"categoryName"];
NSString *cardTypeId = [cellData objectForKey:@"cardTypeId"];
NSString *tipsId = [cellData objectForKey:@"tipsId"];

if([self.defaultCardTypeId containsObject:cardTypeId])
{
    NSUInteger index = [self.defaultCardTypeId indexOfObject:cardTypeId];
    [self.defaultCardTypeId replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:cardTypeId];
}

else{
    [self.defaultCardTypeId addObject:cardTypeId];
}

if([self.defaultTipId containsObject:tipsId])
{
    NSUInteger index = [self.defaultCardTypeId indexOfObject:cardTypeId];
    [self.defaultTipId replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:cardTypeId];
}

else{
    [self.defaultTipId addObject:tipsId];
}

if([cardTypeId isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.jpg"];
    cell.cardTypeImage.image = cellImage;
    cell.cardTypeLabel.text = @"GOOD TO KNOW";
    cell.cardTypeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252/255.0 green:171/255.0 blue:19/255.0 alpha:1];
}

if([cardTypeId isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.jpg"];
    cell.cardTypeImage.image = cellImage;
    cell.cardTypeLabel.text = @"TO CONSIDER";
    cell.cardTypeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:191/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1];
}
cell.notificationCard.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

**FirstViewController:**

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GoalsCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GoalsListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[GoalsCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GoalsListCell"];
    }

    NSInteger indexOfCategory = [self.databaseCall.arrColumnName indexOfObject:@"CategoryName"];
    NSInteger indexOfImage = [self.databaseCall.arrColumnName indexOfObject:@"CategoryImage"];
    NSInteger indexOfActive = [self.databaseCall.arrColumnName indexOfObject:@"coulmn"];

    //Assigning the contents of cell
    cell.goalName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.arrCategoryTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfCategory]];
    NSString *categoryImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.arrCategoryTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfImage]];
    NSString *activeStatus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.arrCategoryTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfActive]];

    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:categoryImage];

    cell.goalImage.image = cellImage;
    [cell.favouriteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(favouriteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    NSMutableString *selectedRowImage = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    //Checking whether the category is selected by user or not
    if([activeStatus isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        selectedRowImage = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"starsel.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        selectedRowImage = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"stardef.png"];
    }

    UIImage *favouriteIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedRowImage];
    [cell.favouriteButton setBackgroundImage:favouriteIconImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Why the first viewcontroller's cellforRowAtIndexPath is called in second viewController

Comment: Unless you have changed the tableview's datasource it is unlikely that it is calling the other classes method.  What behaviour are you seeing exactly?

Comment: @Paulw11 - the contents what i need is shown when the secondViewController cellforRowAtIndexPath is working but not in firstViewController.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to confirm the behaviour you are claiming?  Tableviews are used in literally millions of apps, so it is unlikely that there is a bug such as you are describing.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Yes. I did it.. The firstViewController cellForRowTIndexPath is called when the second row is loading.. Can u pls tell me how to change the datasource.

Comment: It is the `dataSource` property on the `UITableView` instance.

Comment: The problem must be in the dataSource delegate, if you are creating the both tableView by code, put here the code in order to help you. If you are creating in storyboard be sure than the dataSource of each tableView is its viewController.

Comment: Make sure you've set the dataSource property of the correct tableView

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thank you for your time.. I solved this issue  as you told. Can anyone help me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395027/notification-firetime-not-working-sends-notifications-immediately-in-ios/27396463#27396463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i would say sorry for this stupid question.
The problem is due to the tableview datasource as specifies by @Paulw11, @Onik IV, @Kannan Vora. The `secondViewController` `tableView` has the datasource of `firstViewController`.