# Notification fireTime not working. Sends notifications immediately in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications

I have used the following code to send the local notification in particular time. It works fine when calling from a method but when i am calling from another method its not working.

Code as follows:

```
-(void)notificationUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)notificationData
{
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

NSString *tipid = [notificationData objectForKey:@"receivedTipsId"];
NSString *currentDate = [notificationData objectForKey:@"receivedDate"];
NSString *tipsCategoryid = [notificationData objectForKey:@"categoryId"];
NSString *todayDateTime = [notificationData objectForKey:@"todayDate"];
NSString *categoryName = [notificationData objectForKey:@"categoryName"];
NSString *tipsForNotification = [notificationData objectForKey:@"tipsForNotification"];
NSString *cardType = [notificationData objectForKey:@"cardType"];

//Assigning the notification contents
NSDate *updatedDateFormat = [dateFormat dateFromString:todayDateTime];
notification.fireDate = updatedDateFormat;
notification.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:tipid, @"receivedTipsId", currentDate, @"receivedDate", tipsCategoryid, @"categoryId", cardType, @"cardType", nil];
notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",categoryName, tipsForNotification];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of problem with time and date format. When i used this method, I have given the firedate as past date. eg., instead of `dd/MM/yyyy` i used `MM/dd/yyyy`.

So `11/12/2014` is returned as `12/11/2014`. So the notification is received immediately after the notification scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in iOS 8 then you have to register your app for local notification.

IN app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { /*...*/ }

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

And then

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (!localNotification) {
        break;
    }
    **localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];**

    [localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:20]];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"message";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Use above code.